# Get text followed by certain text

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need to get the text but only before the certain text ('---------------').
E.g. example of HTML code:

```
...
<p> This is correct text. Everything after it is wrong</p>
<p>---------------------</p>
<p><strong>This is wrong text</strong></p>
<p> This is wrong another text</p>
...
```

I'm trying to solve this with the next XPath expression:

```
/p/text()[normalize-space()][not(ancestor::p[contains(.,'---')])]
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work as expected.

Would be appreciate for the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath will select the text of a `p` whose immediately following sibling contains `---`:

```
//p[following-sibling::p[contains(.,'---')]][1]/text()
```

Comment: Also, is there any way to just ignore this condition and grab all text if the html doesn't contain '-------------' ?

Comment: Please create a new question and elaborate in detail.  Thanks.

Comment: okay, added: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763887/xpath-grab-text-before-either-of-conditions-occure