# Get text followed by certain text or get all text if that text is missing

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need to get the texts from HTML pages but some of them contain unnecessary texts which go after certain text in page ('---------').
E.g. example of HTML page 1:

```
...
<p> This is correct text. Everything after it is wrong</p>
<p>---------</p>
<p><strong>This is wrong text</strong></p>
<p> This is wrong another text</p>
...
```

Example of HTML page 2:

```
...
<p> This is correct text. Everything after it is wrong</p>
<p> This text is also valid </p>
<p> This is another correct text</p>
...
```

So if page contains '-----------------', I need to grab only texts before it otherways - I need to grab everything. As noted here ([Get text followed by certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744392/get-text-followed-by-certain-text/)) I can use:

```
//p[following-sibling::p[contains(.,'---------')]][1]/text()
```

For the 1st example. But is there a way to use one XPath for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//p[    not(contains(.,'---------')) 
    and not(preceding-sibling::p[contains(.,'---------')])]//text()
```

Will return

```
This is correct text. Everything after it is wrong
```

for your first case and

```
This is correct text. Everything after it is wrong
This text is also valid
This is another correct text
```

for your second case, as requested.

Comment: Thank you, @kjhughes, that works as expected. The only type in your answer is respone for the second case, which is: "

    This is correct text. Everything after it is wrong
    This text is also valid
    This is another correct text
"

Comment: You're welcome, but I didn't understand the rest of your comment.  Is something not entirely correct?

Comment: Just the output, but this was a typo I guess since the solution works good for me.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  Ok, output example is now corrected.   (Probably should clean up these obsolete comments too shortly...)